# How to install .NET Frameworks?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, frameworks

I have a library for my C# project which requires .NET Framework 6.0. Accordingly I want to upgrade my project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6.0.

I have installed .NET 6.0 Runtime and SDK from the [Microsoft](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) website.

Now, after installing and restarting several times, the option to upgrade my project to 6.0 is still not displayed in the dropdown menus. The highest .Net Framework displayed is still 4.8.

When I open the the library I see the .NET 6.0 in the Dropdwon and I am also able to build it but I cannot create my own project or a new project in 6.0.

In the Visual Studio Installer 6.0 is shown as installed, but in the registry and with a [Github tool](https://github.com/jmalarcon/DotNetVersions) which shows me the installed .NET frameworks, 6.0 is not shown.

So I am wondering how to install it correctly so that I can use it for .NET desktop applications. I am on Windows 10 (64Bit 21H1).

[.Net 6.0 is not displayed - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cENF.jpg)

[.Net 6.0 displayed as installed inside the Visual Studio Installer - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTFyF.jpg)

[.Net 6.0 not displayed with the Github version tool - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rALjL.png)

Comment: What is the relationship with C++?

Comment: Also, you seem to be asking why .NET 6 (the continuation of the .NET Core family) isn't accessible under "Windows forms App (**.NET Framework**)" - I would expect the reason for that is pretty self-explanatory: .NET 6 isn't a continuation of .NET Framework. Perhaps try "Windows Forms App (.NET)"?

Comment: I am adding a C++ executable to my C# projekt as resources which requires .Net 6.0

Comment: OK, but how does this specific question relate to C++?

Comment: @Llama It tells me to upgrade my Projekt to 6.0 tho when I want to use the library. And I am inside a .Net Framework Desktop Application. So how is that related, what should I do about that?

Comment: And yes I know that I am able to select a .NET Project (without the framework) to use 6.0 but why requires the .NET Framework project an upgrade to 6.0 if thats not even possible in first place

Comment: _"not even possible"_ - It's not impossible just because it's not something that is automated.

Answer (score 1):

Your current project being .net 4.8 means it runs on `.net framework`, which you can think of as `.net classic`. The next version after 4.8 was actually `.net core` version 1, a massive rework of .net that resulted in significant changes to how you use .net. After Microsoft was happy with everything the next version of .net core after 3 became 5.

As such it is useful to think of .net 4 as last of the `classic .net` era, and any code you wish to move to `modern .net` will likely not be a simple process.

What you should try to do to start is create a new project and make sure to select a .net core template. Odds are you'll need to port things over manually since not everything from .net classic (framework) will easily port over to modern .net (core).

.net framework projects, which will only provide you with .net 4.8 and older versions to choose from:
[image: .net framework]

.net core projects, which will let you choose .net core 1/2/3/5/6:
[image]

These might also be helpful, info from Microsoft about the version differences relating to which one to choose:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, I do know that you can't upgrade it in that way. I mean that it's not the same. .NET is just a package with controls. If there's a new update for .NET then you can only copy-paste the project on a new project with the .NET 6.0 installed, but that won't be necessary if you don't need the new controls or the fixes of the current ones. Also if you are using Visual Studio, in the installation app of Visual Studio there are all the extensions for and versions of Visual Studios. So you can download .NET 6.0 from there. The issue may disappear. Write me back if even of these suggestions of mine worked for you.